# There's a drop down at the bottom of this moodle quiz page, how to remove?

Tags: css, moodle

Still learning here, is it possible to remove the Jump To .... drop down bar by way of CSS?

If not, how can I find the place to change this in Moodle if anyone knows?

Thanks

Moodle Jump To:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extend your css with this:

```
#jump-to-activity {
    display: none !important;
}
```

It will remove element which is selected on your image.

Comment: Wow! That worked. What does the !important do can I ask?

Comment: It makes your styles to override other styles which are applied to that element. Probably it could work without `!important` in your case, probably not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very grateful!